# Pulling previous cell value using conditional lag function

Tags: sql

I am trying to condense down a data table which has separate rows for a particular ID: one row has an intent string and the following rows have one or more log strings.  There can be more than one set of intents/logs for each ID.  I want to pull down the intent string cells in a separate column so they are listed on the same row/s as the associated log strings.

I've "tried" LAG(tobi_intent, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY datevalue) as AssociatedIntent
but firstly, this isn't valid code, and secondly, wouldn't ensure that the associated intent and logs are for the same ID.

Can anyone advise on the correct sql code to get the output below?

expected table output:

```
ID  log intent  associated_intent
1       x   
1   b       x
1   a       x
1       u   
1   f       u
2       x   
2   f       x
5       e   
5   a       e
5   s       e
```